# Чем заменить функцию stoi?

Tags: c++, qt

В программе нужно перевести строку в целое число. Я пытался использовать функцию `stoi` для этой цели, но она не принимается - выходит ошибка:

> ```
> 'stoi' was not declared in this scope
> ```

В частности, мне нужно перевести строку наподобие такой `"5678906576"` в целое число. Я пытался заменить ее на `atoi`, используя предварительно `c_str`. Пишу:

```
string str = "5678906576";
cout << atoi(str.c_str())<< endl;
```

Получаю в консоли `1383939280`.

Тогда я пробую функцию `fromStdString().toInt()` из *Qt Core*. Пишу:

```
string str = "5678906576";
cout << QString::fromStdString(str).toInt() << endl;
```

Получаю 0.

Господа, объясните, пожалуйста, почему так и чем мне тогда заменить `stoi`.

Использую Qt 4.7.4 QtCreator-2.4.1.

Comment: Дополню. У Вас 5678906576 - это не int, это long

Comment: угу и функция соответственно toLong()

Comment: Я вас не сильно огорчу, если скажу, что для вашего примера `stoi` вас не спасет? вам нужна `stoll`

Answer (score 2):

Для использования stoi вам нужно подключить заголовочный файл

```
#include <string>
```

и использовать ее вот так

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str1 = "45";
    std::string str2 = "3.14159";

    int myint1 = std::stoi(str1);
    int myint2 = std::stoi(str2);
}
```

сама функция и использование описаны в [std::stoi, std::stol, std::stoll](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

Answer (score 2):

Так

```
string str = "5678906576";
cout << atoi(str.c_str())<< endl;
```

можно. Но тут у вас проблема выхода за рамки `int`, тут вам нужно было

```
cout << atoll(str.c_str())<< endl;
```

Comment: а какое максимальное число мы можем в int засунуть?

Comment: @Piop `numeric_limits<int>::max()` :) На 32-разрядных платформах - 2^31-1 = 2147483647